# Error while importing Dynamic Web Project into Eclipse Juno

Tags: java, eclipse, exception, eclipse-juno

I'm relatively new to Web Development and I'm facing an issue.I'm trying to import a WAR file into Eclipse Juno and I run into the following error. I'm using Java 1.6.

An internal error occurred during:

> "Loading descriptor for CWP.". java.net.UnknownHostException:
>   java.sun.com

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find a solution for my question. My runtime environment was configured incorrectly to the wrong server since the Dynamic Web Module version was not supported. I had to change the Dynamic Web module version in the Navigation view in the file:

org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.xml

I was then able to choose the appropriate runtime.